# Changing UIWebview frame changes scrollView in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView`with an embedded video as an added subview of a `UIView`. This entire page is done programmatically. I'm animating the frame change of the web view, but its `scrollView` automatically gets resized as soon as I change the frame.

How can I prevent the `webView.scrollView` from resizing whenever I change `webView.frame`?

EDIT: Changing `webView.frame` changes `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` to a value other than `webView.frame.height`. Why?

[image][image]

My minimize view function is:

```
func minimizeViewOnPan() {

        self.btnDown.hidden = true
        var trueOffset: CGFloat = self.initialFirstViewFrame.size.height - 95
        var xOffset: CGFloat = self.initialFirstViewFrame.size.width - 165

        viewFrame.size.width = 160
        viewFrame.size.height = 90
        viewFrame.origin.y = trueOffset
        viewFrame.origin.x = xOffset

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.viewYouTube.frame = self.viewFrame
            // self.viewYouTube.frame & self.viewFrame on iPhone 6: (210.0, 572.0, 160.0, 90.0)

            // self.webView is a subview of self.viewYouTube
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.player.frame.origin.x, self.player.frame.origin.x, self.viewFrame.size.width, self.viewFrame.size.height)
            // On iPhone 6: (0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 90.0)


            }) { (finished) -> Void in

                // add tap gesture
                self.tapRecognizer = nil
                if (self.tapRecognizer == nil) {

                    self.tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "expandViewOnTap:")
                    self.tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                    self.tapRecognizer.delegate = self
                    self.viewYouTube.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapRecognizer)
                }

                self.isExpandedMode = false
                self.minimizedYouTubeFrame = self.viewYouTube.frame

                if (self.direction != nil) && (self.direction == UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection.Down) {

                    self.onView.bringSubviewToFront(self)
                }
        }

    }
```

More than half the video is cut off as is. So my question is, why is the minimized video resized incorrectly?

Comment: It's being resized improperly. The view's `contentSize.height` is wrong. If I can disable this, I can correctly set the `scrollView.zoomScale` to what I want. If I call that now, the `zoomScale` is being applied to the wrong `contentSize.height`. And manually calling `contentSize.height` does nothing.

Comment: Actually, I refined my question so it would give other users a better idea. `webView.scrollView` is resizing incorrectly because its `contentSize.height` is incorrect, which I can't set myself. I'd sincerely appreciate a solution or constructive feedback.

Comment: See updated @matt. Hopefully that should articulate my question better.

Comment: I'm using a YouTube iFrame, which is only able to be displayed in a UIWebView. I'm almost positive it resized perfectly on iOS 8/Swift 1.3. Once I updated to iOS 9/Swift 2/Xcode 7 I got the problem.

Comment: Ok I've confirmed that the code worked great in iOS 8/Swift 1.3, and that I only started getting this error once I updated both. I haven't changed any code other than updating syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. We were displaying a YouTube iFrame with constant height 210. So when the view was minimized, I couldn't call `contentSize` because it was controlled by the JS iFrame. So since height of the video was 210, and height of the webview was 90, we used `self.player.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 60)` ((210/2)-(90/2)=60) to offset height of the view.